# Setting ScrollView Height

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I have a window. That window has a header (variable size) and should have a scrollable body that sits directly under the header. How can I set the height of the body so that it actually scrolls? If I set `height: 'auto'`, the body extends beyond the bottom of the viewport to fit all of its content. If I set its `top` and `bottom` properties, nothing shows up at all.

I can't imagine that I'm the only one who's come across this, but I haven't found a single definitive answer for how to create properly sized, scrollable view within a window. Heights seem tricky since the value is so different in portrait and landscape modes on a *single* device, much less across devices.

Can someone provide tips on how to manage this scenario? I'm hoping I can extrapolate it to handle other view height scenarios.

Thanks.

Comment: Rob Wilkerson, The scrollview will not scroll until the height is more than your screen size vertically and the child elements of the scroll are positioned below the original screen view. In case of iPhone, if you start the scroll with top:45 you can set scroll contentHeight to maybe 320 or more.

Comment: Thanks, Muhammad. The maddening thing is that this seems so simple. I have a header. Immediately beneath that sits a `ScrollView` with a bunch of content. If I set no height explicitly, nothing appears. I have to set a height, but I want to set it to the remaining height of the viewport.

Comment: Did you try to set property `contentHeight` instead of height? Otherwise put your code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you're trying to create a ScrollView that just has the ability to scroll when empty, you should add a empty View into the ScrollView, which has the "top" property.

For example:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();
var scrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView();
var emptyView = Ti.UI.createView({top: 460});
scrollView.add(emptyView)
win.add(scrollView);
```

Note that the "top" property has 460 set, which is 40 bigger than the iPhone screen res of "420". This will case the scrollView to scroll. If you're looking for a specific size based on the window's navBar controlTitle, you will have to run an equation based on what you think the size will be, applying that size to the view's "top" property accordingly.